# How to ignore arbitrary tokens using parsec?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I wanted to replace `sed` and `awk` with Parsec. For example, extract number from strings like `unknown structure but containing the number 42 and maybe some other stuff`.

I run into "unexpected end of input". I'm looking for equivalent of non-greedy `.*([0-9]+).*`.

```
module Main where

import Text.Parsec

parser :: Parsec String () Int
parser = do
    _ <- many anyToken
    x <- read <$> many1 digit
    _ <- many anyToken
    return x

main :: IO ()
main = interact (show . parse parser "STDIN")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily done with my library [regex-applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-applicative). It gives you both the combinator interface and the features of regular expressions that you seem to want.

Here's a working version that's closest to your example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ApplicativeDo #-}
import Text.Regex.Applicative
import Text.Regex.Applicative.Common (decimal)

parser :: RE Char Int
parser = do
    _ <- few anySym
    x <- decimal
    _ <- many anySym
    return x

main :: IO ()
main = interact (show . match parser)
```

Here's an even shorter version, using `findFirstInfix`:

```
import Text.Regex.Applicative
import Text.Regex.Applicative.Common (decimal)

main :: IO ()
main = interact (snd3 . findFirstInfix decimal)
  where snd3 (_, r, _) = r
```

If you want to perform actual tokenization (e.g. skip `93` in `foo93bar`), then take a look at [lexer-applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lexer-applicative), a tokenizer based on regex-applicative.

Comment: Roman's library is really nice and definitely solves this problem. Just one note: I think Roman meant to use the non-greedy `few` combinator in this answer instead of `many`, like `_ <- few anySym`.

Comment: @JamesBrock on the contrary, I wanted to demonstrate that sevo's code would work with minimal modifications (so preserving their `many`), even despite the fact that `many` is greedy! The code will correctly extract 42 from sevo's example, which may be counterintuitive if you're used to Parsec's semantics. But regex-applicative will find the successful branch if it exists at all, even if a failing branch is prioritized by the greedy `many`. The difference between `many` and `few` is that if there are multiple numbers, `many` will find the last one whereas `few` will find the first one.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but when I run your example code (the first one) on the example input, I get `Just 2`. When I change `many` to `few`, I get `Just 42`. @roman-cheplyaka

Comment: I take your general point about `regex-applicative` being able to find successful branches without explicit backtracking though, which is cool.

Comment: @JamesBrock ouch! That makes sense. I thought I'd tested the code, but apparently not. I've made the change; thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing `sed` and `awk` with parsers is what the
[replace-megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/)
library is all about.

Extract numbers from unstructured strings with the
[`sepCap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:sepCap)
parser combinator.

```hs
import Replace.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char.Lexer

parseTest (sepCap (decimal :: Parsec Void String Int))
  $ "unknown structure but containing the number 42 and maybe some other stuff"
```

```hs
[ Left "unknown structure but containing the number "
, Right 42
, Left " and maybe some other stuff"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work, since `anyToken` accepts and consumes - as its names says - any token, including digits. And you apply it `many` times. Therefore the attempt to read digits with the second parser must fail. There simply cannot be any tokens left.

Instead make your first parser accept any character, that is not a digit (using `isDigit` from module `Data.Char`):

```
parser :: Parsec String () Int
parser = do
    _ <- many $ satisfy (not . isDigit)
    x <- read <$> many1 digit
    _ <- many anyToken
    return x
```

Comment: True, but I was hoping to allow arbitrary tokens, including overlapping patterns. Performance is not important here so backtracking is absolutely fine.

Comment: I doubt you'd be happy with exponential-time backtracking, which can easily happen when you attempt to match text over-carelessly. Really a parser is just not well suited for extracting meaning from input with no structure. Why not just use a regex, if that's what you want?